# Lua - If local x,y,z, and an x,y,z has been declared, are they the same or are they different?

Tags: variables, lua, local

```
function PedsPrepareConversation(ped1,ped2,distance,walkSpeed)
PlayerSetPunishmentPoints(0)
  if PedGetWeapon(gPlayer) == 437 then
    PedSetWeapon(gPlayer,-1)
  end
  if PedIsInAnyVehicle(gPlayer) then
    PedWarpOutOfCar(gPlayer)
  end
  PedStop(ped2)
  local x,y,z = PedGetPosXYZ(ped2)
  PedMoveToXYZ(ped1,walkSpeed,x,y,z)
  local r1 = x + distance
  local r2 = y + distance
  local r3 = x - distance
  local r4 = y - distance
  x,y,z = PedGetPosXYZ(ped1)
  PedFaceXYZ(ped2,x,y,z)
  repeat
 Wait(0)
  until PedInRectangle(ped1,r1,r2,r3,r4)
  PedStop(ped1)
  x,y,z = PedGetPosXYZ(ped2)
  PedFaceXYZ(ped1,x,y,z)
  x,y,z = PedGetPosXYZ(ped1)
  PedFaceXYZ(ped2,x,y,z)
end
```

I was programming in Lua and I was a bit confused at the declaration of the variables.  Since "local" has been declared on one instance of x,y,z and then another instance of x,y,z has been declared below does that mean that they are different variables or are they the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you are showing `x,y,z` are only declared once (as local) and then are assigned new values multiple times. The other x, y, z are all in the same scope as the local x, y, z and appear after the declaration. Here are some examples

```
do -- new scope
  local x,y,z = 'a','b','c' -- declared local
  print(x, y, z)   -- prints a b c
  do
    x,y,z = 1,2,3   -- new scope, but still referring to the local x, y, z (higher scope)
    print(x, y, z)  -- prints 1 2 3
  end
  print(x, y, z) -- prints 1 2 3 (modified the original)
end -- end local x, y, z scope (now they are garbage)
-- global scope, no x, y, z is defined here 
print(x, y, z)   -- prints nil nil nil
```

Scope is a big concept so check out [Scope Tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ScopeTutorial) for a more thorough discussion.

Comment: I would like to ask why you have added two do-ends however, why did you do it?  Would it make a difference if you left it out?

Comment: the do-end pairs create a new scope. Since x, y, z are local, they are local to the do-end pair they are created in and they become garbage once we get to `end` of the pair.

Comment: @VeridisQuo In your example x, y, z are declared in the function, and they become garbage when you get to the `end` of the function.

Answer (score 0):

This is discussed at length in section 4.2 of [PIL](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.2.html). Because your `local x,y,z` is in the same "block" of code as the `x,y,z=...`, they are the same.